# How remove two character from a String?

Tags: java

`NAI-PO-0009-1`  this is original string. I need to remove `-1`, especially the last special char and the end char.  I tried but could not get to remove two charecters from the end of the string.

Answer (score 2):

Do following:

```
String test="NAI-PO-0009-1";
test=test.substring(0, test.length()-2);
System.out.println(test);
```

**Output :**

```
NAI-PO-0009
```

For more on such methods visit [link](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html).

Answer (score 1):

if you want to remove the last accorance of "-" til the end do:

```
String a="NAI-PO-0009-1";
System.out.println(a.substring(0, a.lastIndexOf('-'))-1);
```

if you just want to remove last to chars

```
System.out.println(a.substring(0, test.length()-2);
```

`lastIndexOf` finds and return the last appearance of a char.

`substring` return a sub string to the origin string begins with the character at the specified index and extends to the end of this string or up to endIndex - 1 if second argument is given.

Answer (score 0):

Like @Darshan Lila said,

```
String test="NAI-PO-0009-1";
test=test.substring(0, test.length()-2);
System.out.println(test);
```

works for removing last two characters. If instead also need to remove the last special char and everything behind, you will have to use:

```
String test="NAI-PO-0009-1";
test=test.substring(0, test.lastIndexOf("-") -1); 
/*explain: second parameter of SubString() method is for the length of the resulting 
string, on a zero-based index, it has to end the last char before the last dash*/
System.out.println(test);
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Why `_`? Should be `-`.